# TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'map' - AngularJS2

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, angular2-services, subscribe

I have service file which is returning a subscribable result on some condition(obviously making an http call) and returning a normal object on some other conditions. Since I have used `.subscribe` in `component.ts` for calling this service method, getting "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'map'" on condition where http calls are not happening.

`component.ts` file code

```
    this.myservice.userAuthenticate( 'user' ).subscribe(result => {

        console.log('results', result);
    });
```

and my service file is like this

```
    public userAuthenticate(user ): Observable<any> {

    const expired = this.expiry.hasExpired();
    if ( expired ) 

            return this.userService.generateUserId('some input' ).map( data => {
                this.CheckUser( User);
                return <any>userInfo;
            } );
        }
    } else {

        return this.CheckUser( User).map( response => {
            return <any>userInfo;
        } );
    }
```

In the else part, the Im just getting data from storage and processing it using `CheckUser`  method. There is no http calls are happening and it is giving me the above error. Is there any way I can return a subscribable result even without a http calls ?

One work around is to have this check from component file and only subscribe for first part, but I have to make the same changes in lot of places as this particular method in many places. Could anyone please let me know how can I give a subscribable response in else condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that `this.CheckUser(User)` isn't returning an Observable.

I'm not completely sure what your code does and why you're `this.CheckUser(User)` chaining with `map` while above you're not which is kind of confusing but still you can wrap the method call with `Observable.of()`:

```
return Observable.of(this.CheckUser(User)).map(response => {
  return <any>userInfo;
});
```

Eventually you could use `Observable.defer(() => this.CheckUser(User))` if you want the callback to be invoked only after you subscribe to this chain.

Comment: I have removed map and Observable.of('return value') worked for me. Also I have used import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'; Thanks for your help